# Ionic 3, angular 4.3 application to android device deployment failed

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

When I run the command `ionic cordova run android --device` I get the following error. Has anyone else experienced this type of issue before, I'm not being able to deploy my app on my phone. I'm running this on Windows 10.

> BUILD FAILED in 13s (node:10556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
  Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.aar
  Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.aar

Thanks.

Comment: Did you google this error message? Just googling gives results, have you tried any of those? If so, show us.

Comment: Uff yes i did and this issue helped me out. https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/414 thanks for your feedback on my post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is :
editing the build.gradle file which is located in platforms/android/build.gradle line where it says allprojects {...}

the structure should be like this :

```
`allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}`
```

so maven should go before jcenter().

Answer (score 0):

Editing the build.gradle file can be a pain, since removing & re-adding the platform will step on those changes.  Consider a new developer adding the android platform for the first time - now they need to also manually edit this build.gradle file.

I personally found the error in this post was resolved by fixing some android support library version incompatibilities.  I did that by installing the `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` plugin with the command below:

`ionic cordova-android-support-gradle-release  --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+`

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release